# How to implement mod in solr query

Tags: solr, lucene, modulo

I am looking for a way to query solr with mod function, like q=mod(id):2 which will return docs whose id mod 2 equal to 0. It's there a way do that kind of search? Thanks

Comment: You can check this page http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery

Comment: Are you using solr without any library build on top?

Answer (score 3):

I have found the solution. Using function in fq is perfect. Query seem like:

```
q=subject:mp3&fq={!frange l=0 u=1}mod(id,2)
```

http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api-4_0_0-BETA/org/apache/solr/search/FunctionRangeQParserPlugin.html